# Error in TablePagination in Material-UI API

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a component in TablePagination. I have successfully did it BUT I saw a problem in my console. It says `warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.`

Codesandbox: [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-iv5ibp?file=/demo.js)

I don't know if there's any alternative to this? I'm using Material v4.

```
        <TablePagination
          component="div"
          count={data.persons && data.persons.length}
          page={page}
          rowsPerPage={1}
          labelDisplayedRows={() => {
            return (
              <>
                <span style={{ marginRight: '1rem' }}>Page</span>
                <Select value={page} onChange={handlePageChange}>
                  {data.persons &&
                    data.persons.map((value, index) => {
                      return (
                        <MenuItem key={index} value={index}>
                          {index + 1}
                        </MenuItem>
                      );
                    })}
                </Select>
              </>
            );
          }}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[1]}
          onChangePage={handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
```

Comment: Is `component="div"` necessary? It does not seem to be a  requirement for the `TablePagination` component. You may want to consider using classes `<TablePagination className={classes.myclassname}`

Comment: Could you please include the code of the  componenent that is wrapping this <TablePagination />

Comment: @Jamie_D. The error is on the `labelDisplayedRows`

Comment: @WebstraDev. The error is on the `labelDisplayedRows`

Comment: try    component="span" and share your code in online editor i.e. stackbliz

Comment: @AvaniBataviya. Still the error. The error is because of `labelDisplayedRows`

Comment: can you please share you code with same dependency version in online editor as i am not getting error in latest material ui version for your code

Comment: @AvaniBataviya. Here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-iv5ibp?file=/demo.js

Comment: i have checked you code component="span" is not supoorted here it's only working in material ui latest verion